Javascript replacing child nodes causing them to change to [object HTMLTableSectionElement]
I am trying to convert a table to remove some tags used that I don't want, programmatically. I wrote a recursive function that gets called on the table element, and calls itself on all children, making a list of those children and replacing the current children with these sanitized children. However the nodes don't get added correctly, but instead a string representation of [object HTMLTableSectionElement] or [object Text] ends up in the output.
(For those interested in context: I use thead, tbody, and a couple custom tags for a fancy table, but I also want to be able to press a button to copy the table into wikipedia pages which don't support those tags, so while copying to clipboard I have to remove them or it looks terrible)
This is my function:
function prepHTMLforExport(element){
    //recursively goes into an HTML element, preparing it for export by:
    //removing thead and tbody statements but leaving their contents in the parent element
    //removing floattext tags
    //replacing hyperlink a tags with ...
    
    //go through child elements and prep each for export
    var newchildren = []
    var children = element.childNodes
    for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        var newkid = prepHTMLforExport(children[i])
        
        //if the new kid is actually a list, concat the lists
        if (newkid instanceof Array){
            newchildren.concat(newkid)
        } else {
            newchildren.push(newkid)
        }
    }
    //if to be removed, return a list of children
    if (element.tagName in ["floattext", "table-body", "table-head"]){
        return newchildren
    } else {
        //else add children to self and return self
        if (newchildren.length > 0) {
            element.replaceChildren(newchildren)
        }
        return element
    }
}

It should work on basically any HTML table.
I suspected originally that I was checking the wrong children or using the wrong method to replace them, so I also tried it with var children = element.children, and I looked if there was a different function for the replacement, like replaceWith, but on closer inspection I discovered that this didn't help. Elements already get converted to the wrong form in the nodelist of their parents while they are being processed, not only after I get them replaced with their sanitized version. To test this, there is this table:
<table>
  <th>sample text</th> 
  <th>some more sample text</th>
</table>

When stepping through the code, if the code is just done preparing the first cell and if now about the recurse into the second cell, if you execute console.log(element), this results in
<table>
  <th>[object Text]</th>
  <th>some more sample text</th>
</table>


Whenever you see [object Object] or some other [object Type] it means your code has converted an object to a string.  eg let txt = "x" + obj

Likely off topic: array concat - returns a new array, your code ignores this

Try changing to newchildren = newchildren.concat(newkid); and element.replaceChildren(...newchildren) - appears to work (at least no error) : https://jsfiddle.net/xfnjozhw/1/ but the output appears to be the same as the input, so I have no idea if it's worked or not.

Hmm, so then the question becomes where does that string appear and why...
Thanks for the note on concat, I fixed that now in my code

Your issue is that .element.replaceChildren expects each child to be a separate parameter, however you are passing an array.  Try with element.replaceChildren(...newchildren) replaceChildren

@fdomn-m That works indeed! The filtering doesn't yet but that seems like a different issue to me. What does the ... do exactly? is it an unpacking operator like the python *?

I had an answer prepared with details, but didn't know if it would work for you. It's the "rest parameters" which converts array to param list.   In js there's also the spread operator which looks the same.

Your issue is that .element.replaceChildren expects each child to be a separate parameter, however you are passing an array.
So .replaceChildren converts the array to a string, giving
[object Text],[object HTMLTableSectionElement]

the extra , comma in the middle is an additional hint that this was an array converted to a string
You can convert an array to parameters using rest parameters - that line of your code becomes:
element.replaceChildren(...newchildren)

Updated snippet:


function prepHTMLforExport(element) {
  //recursively goes into an HTML element, preparing it for export by:
  //removing thead and tbody statements but leaving their contents in the parent element
  //removing floattext tags
  //replacing hyperlink a tags with ...

  //go through child elements and prep each for export
  var newchildren = []
  var children = element.childNodes
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var newkid = prepHTMLforExport(children[i])

    //if the new kid is actually a list, concat the lists
    if (newkid instanceof Array) {
      newchildren = newchildren.concat(newkid);
    } else {
      newchildren.push(newkid)
    }
  }
  //if to be removed, return a list of children
  if (element.tagName in ["floattext", "table-body", "table-head"]) {
    return newchildren
  } else {
    //else add children to self and return self
    if (newchildren.length > 0) {
      element.replaceChildren(...newchildren);
    }
    return element
  }
}

prepHTMLforExport(document.getElementById("tbl"));
<table id='tbl'>
  <th>sample text</th>
  <th>some more sample text</th>
</table>




In addition to the array mentioned by @fdomn-m in his answer, there are three other issues I see.
Using element.childNodes can return text nodes like " " or "\n", not just element nodes. Using element.children will fix that.
element.tagNames, returns tags in uppercase and you are comparing to lowercase strings.
Finally, you are comparing against "table-head" and "table-body" tags. I presume that you meant "thead" and "tbody". I don't know what the floattext is that you are checking for.
EDIT: As you can see in the code comments, I also changed your
in [] to be [].includes()
Here is your code with all three of those changes.


function fancyTableOnClick( event ) {
      prepHTMLforExport( FancyTableID )
    }


    function prepHTMLforExport(element){
    //recursively goes into an HTML element, preparing it for export by:
    //removing thead and tbody statements but leaving their contents in the parent element
    //removing floattext tags
    //replacing hyperlink a tags with ...

    //go through child elements and prep each for export
    var newchildren = []
    // var children = element.childNodes
    var children = element.children  // Just elements, no text nodes
    for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        var newkid = prepHTMLforExport(children[i])

        //if the new kid is actually a list, concat the lists
        if (newkid instanceof Array){
            newchildren = newchildren.concat(newkid)
        } else {
            newchildren.push(newkid)
        }
    }
    //if to be removed, return a list of children
    // if (element.tagName in ["floattext", "table-body", "table-head"]){
    if (["FLOATTEXT", "TBODY", "THEAD"].includes(element.tagName)){  // [].includes() not "in []"
        return newchildren
    } else {
        //else add children to self and return self
        if (newchildren.length > 0) {
            // element.replaceChildren(newchildren)
            element.replaceChildren(...newchildren)  // Takes individual elements, not an array
        }
        return element
    }
}
table {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 4px;
}
tbody {
  background-color: green;
}
thead {
  background-color: cyan;
}
<button type="button" onclick="fancyTableOnClick(event)">Fix Table</button>

      <table id="FancyTableID">
        <thead>
          <th>sample text</th>
          <th>Something</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <h>Table body</th>
          <th>some more sample text</th>
        </tbody>
      </table>



